# Currency "EUR" not found - Store is down!

Tags: error, currency

I get this error every day once or twice.
We Need to clear the Cache via FTP - after this the shop works again.
We have no idea why - we cannot reproduce the error.
Sometimes it´s presented at night - sometimes in the morning or during the day.

Here is a screenshot of the error - i need help - PLS!

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-30115556/image.png.html

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

There is a note in the code:

```
* catch specific exceptions like "Currency 'USD' not found"
* - back end falls with specific locals as Malaysia and etc.
*
* as we can see from Zend framework ticket
* http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10038
* zend team is not going to change it behaviour in the near time
```

The exception is thrown here: /lib/Zend/Currency.php line 124

Try to change the code below:

```
if (($this->_options['currency'] === null) and ($this->_options['name'] === null)) {
    #require_once 'Zend/Currency/Exception.php';
    throw new Zend_Currency_Exception("Currency '$options' not found");
}
```

To this one:

```
if (($this->_options['currency'] === null) and ($this->_options['name'] === null)) {
    #require_once 'Zend/Currency/Exception.php';
    Mage::log($this->getLocale(),null,'curr.log');
    $this->setLocale('en_US');
    //throw new Zend_Currency_Exception("Currency '$options' not found");
}
```

Comment: Hi if i open /lib/Zend/Currency.php you can see this: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-30210308/Unbenannt1.jpg.html

Comment: I have modified the answer. Please, check.

Comment: The Problem is the APC our Server. My Hoster told me After my Cache is Full the Site is down. Now After the Cache is Full the Rest will Save in the Database

Comment: For reference, this happened on two sites after setting up memcache